# Missing first row in array output

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, foreach

When I try to iterate through some results of a SQL query, I don't see the first entry. The following is in an outer loop with different input for the query. Some versions return one row, others return up to ten but the first row is always missing. The display line beginning "Current entry" always starts from 2. I know that Perl arrays start at zero but the "foreach" doesn't ask for specific numbers - just to show each array element. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Thanks.

```
  $OurSQL = "select DISTINCT BORROWER.BARCODE, POST_CODE, SURNAME, FIRST_NAMES, ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."LOAN.CREATE_LOCATION FROM ADDRESS, CONTACT_POINT, BORROWER ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."left join LOAN on (BORROWER.BORROWER_ID = LOAN.BORROWER_ID) ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."where (BORROWER.BORROWER_ID = CONTACT_POINT.BORROWER_ID) and ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."(CONTACT_POINT.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID) and ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."(upper(BORROWER.SURNAME) = upper('".$sname."') and upper(BORROWER.FIRST_NAMES) = upper('".$fname."')) and ";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."(ADDRESS.POST_CODE = '".$postcode."') AND (LOAN.CREATE_DATE >";
  $OurSQL = $OurSQL."dateadd(year, -1, getdate())) ORDER BY POST_CODE, SURNAME, FIRST_NAMES, CREATE_LOCATION";

$lib = 0;
  (@our_usage) = &sql($d, $OurSQL);
  # Iterate through array returned for the current borrower
  foreach $entry (@our_usage)
  {
    # Put current line into our variables
    $lib++;
    print "Current entry ($lib): $entry\n";
    ($ourbcode, $ourpcode, $oursname, $ourfnames, $ourloc) = split('~', $entry);
    $ourline = "$ourbcode $ourpcode $oursname $ourfnames $ourloc";
    # Show each line on screen
    print $ourline."\n";
    print OUT $ourline."\n";
  } # End of results loop
```

Comment: `$lib++;` You are incrementing first then printing the value of `index` `1` element rather than `element` of `index` `0`, Move it to after `print` statement.

Comment: Put a `next;` after the first `print` line. What does that show?

Comment: @AbhiNickz: You're right, but the OP says *"The display line beginning "Current entry" always starts from 2"*. Your comment doesn't explain that.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us. If `$lib` is 2 on the first iteration, which from the code we see it can't, maybe `&sql()` changes `$lib`?

Comment: You should check the contents of `@our_usage` with the `use Data::Dumper; 
print Dumper(\@our_usage);` that should debug the cause, only if array elements count is small.

Comment: Since you don't have `use strict` and you're not declaring your variables in a lexical scope with `my`, @Jens has a good point. If you have another variable `$lib` inside of `sub sql { ... }`, that will be **the same variable** as the `$lib` in this part of your code, because Perl makes all variables into package variables if you don't declare them with `my`. Thus, you'd be changing the same thing from a different piece of code. That's why you should **always** have `use strict` in your code, it would tell you about it. Also include `use warnings` to see what else you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What I'd expected was to see element 0 of each query result array (the first element) numbered as Current entry (1) but that never appears. I've tried inserting "next;"  after "print current entry" and it seems to make no difference. I'll add "use strict" and see if that throws any errors.

Comment: I guess my problems are more fundamental coming from Pascal, where variable declarations are strict but straightforward. I thought I had a reasonable grasp of the basics of Perl but adding "use strict" gives a long list of "requires explicit package" errors and a whole new area I need to understand.

Comment: @Jens, I've added the code for the SQL, which doesn't refer to $lib. Will double check that I haven't used $lib elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code for us to see what exactly is going wrong.
Here's a complete script that works, using fixed strings instead of calling `sql()` in the hope you can transform it to something working for you.

```
$ cat x.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use strict;

# ...your other code here...

my @our_usage = ("a~b~c~d~e", "1~2~3~4~5", "R~S~T~U~V");
# Iterate through array returned for the current borrower
my $lib = 0;
foreach my $entry (@our_usage)
{
  # Put current line into our variables
  $lib++;
  print "Current entry ($lib): $entry\n";
  my ($ourbcode, $ourpcode, $oursname, $ourfnames, $ourloc) = split('~', $entry);
  my $ourline = "$ourbcode $ourpcode $oursname $ourfnames $ourloc";
  # Show each line on screen
  print $ourline."\n";
} # End of results loop
```

Sample run:

```
$ perl ./x.pl
Current entry (1): a~b~c~d~e
a b c d e
Current entry (2): 1~2~3~4~5
1 2 3 4 5
Current entry (3): R~S~T~U~V
R S T U V
```

Comment: Many thanks (belatedly!). (I wasn't able to use strict because my service (database) provider gave me the connection string (in a library) and they don't use strict, but I found some way round the problem.)